# ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Application startup error! Code: APP_CONTAINER_CRASHED /bin/sh: 1: exec: gunicorn: not found

Tags: google-compute-engine, django, google-app-engine

I am deploying my Django project on google cloud app engine with my virtual environment I get the error
**ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9]
Application startup error! Code: APP_CONTAINER_CRASHED
/bin/sh: 1: exec: gunicorn: not found** i already install gunicorn  and my app.yaml

```
runtime: python
env: flex
  entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT tiwari.wsgi
automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 1
  max_num_instances: 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say you "installed gunicorn" do you mean `pip install gunicorn?` If so, that won't work. This installs it locally (or on a virtual env if you're using one). However when you come to deploy your app [using `gcloud app deploy`] GAE configures a new docker image and install dependancies listed in your `requirements.txt` file. So unless `gunicorn` is listed in there it will not be installed in your docker image and therefore won't be accessible to your code.

So, in your `requirements.txt` you need to specify:
`gunicorn==19.3.0`

Hope that helps